# Wordpress Woocommerce Advanced Custom Field True/False always returns NULL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a `advanced-custom-field` of the type `true/false`. The purpose is to either show some products of my woocommerce shop or not. For some reason, the result is always `NULL` and I don't know why. I also sat the field only show on the  shop page (which uses the archive-products.php)

Here is what I try:

```
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

woocommerce_product_loop_start();

if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
}
if(get_field('show_tab')) : ?>
<li class="extra">';
   ...show some stuff
</li>
<?php endif;
echo '</ul>';

} else {

  do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}
```

Like mentioned above, the True/False field always returns `NULL`

Can someone help me out

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_field('show_tab')` is outside of the loop of the products. Put it inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) outside of the Loop, so you need to also give it the ID of the post you are trying to get the field from, like so:

`if(get_field('show_tab', $post_id)) : ?>`

Having said that, your code looks a bit messy, so I'm assuming that you meant for it to be within the loop. If so, move that all up, perhaps after `do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );` then you won't need to add the ID and it should work as is.